# jQuery add hover to dynamically generated element

Tags: jquery

I create element below dynamically

```
<ul class="services-list clearfix">
                    <li class="services-1" data-service-title="Hint 1"></li>
                    <li class="services-2" data-service-title="Hint 1"></li>
                    <li class="services-3" data-service-title="Hint 1"></li>
                    <li class="services-4" data-service-title="Hint 1"></li>
                    <li class="services-5" data-service-title="Hint 1"></li>
                    <li class="services-6" data-service-title="Hint 1"></li>
                </ul>
```

and then I need to add hover to this element.

I tried this code

```
$('.services-list > li').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var service_title = $(this).data( 'service-title' );
        $('<span class="service-hint"></span>').text(service_title).appendTo($(this));
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('.services-list > li').find('.service-hint').remove();
    }
});
```

and this

```
$(document).on('hover', '.services-list > li', function () {
    var service_title = $(this).data( 'service-title' );
    $('<span class="service-hint"></span>').text(service_title).appendTo($(this));
}, function () {
    $('.services-list > li').find('.service-hint').remove();
});
```

but they don't work both. What's wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: did you include the jquery library?

Comment: of course! the first script works for static element, but doesn't work for dynamically generated element.

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: @hronikata first script is working fine only , not for you ?

Comment: try to make a function in stead of $(document).on... but in your li use onhover="dofunction(this)" or something.

Answer (score 1):

The first area is just a normal .on() event, since you created in an object format, you can put the `parent` context / selector at the end. This will make it a delegated event.

```
$('.services-list > li').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        /* code */
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        /* code */
    }
}, $('body') ); // <-- now it's delegated to the parent context of body
            // use something more specific, maybe an ID of an <div> around your area
```

This *should* do the trick.

Also, as a side note:

Don't use `document` (or as I showed `body` above) as a parent context. That's one of the main reasons they removed `.live()` from the jQuery library. Make it much more specific, so the event doesn't bubble on EVERY mouseover on your page. Make it soething more specific! `#parentDiv` or something.

Comment: this script doesn't work for static and dynamically generated elements both :(

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Sorry, look at my edit now. That will do the trick! @hronikata I had to wrap it in `$('body')` and it worked. Strange, but it worked in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

If your only concern is to show additional text on `mouseover` that can be available at the time these elements are added, I recommend using pure CSS to achieve the functionality:

**HTML code**

```
<ul class="services-list clearfix">
    <li class="services-1" data-service-title="Hint 1">Service 1 <span class="hint">Hint 1</span></li>
    <li class="services-2" data-service-title="Hint 1">Service 2 <span class="hint">Hint 2</span></li>
    <li class="services-3" data-service-title="Hint 1">Service 3 <span class="hint">Hint 3</span></li>
    <li class="services-4" data-service-title="Hint 1">Service 4 <span class="hint">Hint 4</span></li>
    <li class="services-5" data-service-title="Hint 1">Service 5 <span class="hint">Hint 5</span></li>
    <li class="services-6" data-service-title="Hint 1">Service 6 <span class="hint">Hint 6</span></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS code**

```
.services-list li span {
    display: none;
}

.services-list li:hover span {
    display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jghr2cgv/

---

If that is not possible, you are on the right path with [jQuery delegate events](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('.services-list-container').on('mouseenter', '.services-list li', function () {
    // Mouse over $(this) element, even if the element was added later, but container was present initially
});
```

You must attach this type of event handling to an element that is present at the time the event is bound. I recommend a container for that task instead of `document`, as implied in the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be trying :

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.services-list > li', function () {
var service_title = $(this).data( 'service-title' );
$('<span class="service-hint"></span>').text(service_title).appendTo($(this));
 }, function () {
$('.services-list > li').find('.service-hint').remove();
});
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hk87V/32/)